# Encoding facebook graph with loopj's AsyncHttpClient

Tags: java, android, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get a response from facebook graph API with loopj's AsyncHttpClient but I'm having problems with the encoding.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/Google?fields=posts.limit(15){message,object_id,type,updated_time},name,picture&access_token=########|########
```

When I pass this url to get(), I get a `IllegalArgumentException`:

```
 Illegal character in query at index 82: https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/Google?fields=posts.limit(15){message,object_id,type,updated_time},name,picture&access_token=########|########
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 82: ttps://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/Google?fields=posts.limit(15){message,object_id,type,updated_time},name,picture&access_token=########|########
            at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:727)
            at org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet.<init>(HttpGet.java:75)
            at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient.get(AsyncHttpClient.java:612)
            at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient.get(AsyncHttpClient.java:599)
            at com.aufmschoolbliz.app.activities.TestFacebookFragment.onCreateView(TestFacebookFragment.java:60)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1504)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:942)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1121)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1484)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:482)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1073)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:249)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:543)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I tried setting the URL encoding to true and false by `setURLEncodingEnabled()` but it gives the same exception. Also tried URLEncoder class but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by passing the parts of the URL to the constructor of URI:

```
URL url = new URL("the graph url");
URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());
url = uri.toURL();
return url.toString();
```